# Can I get data from a specific location in an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to assign a value in a location to a string.  I can't figure out how to set up the attribute portion of this.

```
string type = null;

type = xmlNodeComplex4.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.Attributes["@ID"+ RefID1].FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.FirstChild.InnerText;
```

This isn't working.  The part where I have FirstChild.Attributes["@ID" + RefID1] doesn't work.  The code compiles with no problem.. but this line takes a dump and I get an error.  I know it is in how I'm trying to access the attribute portion.  I've tried many different combinations for the data in the [ ]. Is there a way to do this, if so, can someone direct me in the right direction.

The RefID is a string which contains data like this _154.   That FirstChild position has an attribute that looks like this.

```
<CATALOG>
  <OBJECTS>
    <REFS ID = "_150">
        <CITY>Centerville</CITY>
        <STATE>Ohio</STATE>
        <ZIP>45459</ZIP>
    </REFS>

    <REFS ID = "_154">
        <CITY>Troy</CITY>
        <STATE>Michigan</STATE>
        <ZIP>48083</ZIP>
    </REFS>

  </OBJECTS>
  <PLANT>
     <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
     <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
     <ZONE>4</ZONE>
     <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
     <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
     <RefID1>_0154</RefID1>

  </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: What XML file you are talking about? And what node you want to get?

Comment: Let me build an Example for you.

Comment: `.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling` is insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that tiny snippet of your XML, I can only suggest to use `SelectSingleNode()` with general XPath like this :

```
string xpath = String.Format("//DATA[@ID='{0}'", RefID1);
string state = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
```

Above XPath means select `<DATA>` element, at any level within xml document, having attribute ID value equals value of `RefID1`.

**UPDATE :**

Given the updated XML, you can try this way :

```
string xpath = String.Format("//REFS[@ID='{0}']/STATE", RefID1);
string data = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
```

or if you really need the query to be relative to `xmlNodeComplex4` :

```
string xpath = String.Format("./../preceding-sibling::OBJECTS/REFS[@ID='{0}']/STATE", RefID1);
var state = xmlNodeComplex4.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
```

You can see XPath `/..` is similar to `ParentNode` and `/preceding-sibling` is similar to `PreviousSibling`.

Comment: I just added an example code of some xml to keep it easy.  So lets say the xmlNodeComplex4 part of my code given is pointing to the ZONE node... So want to get to the STATE node.  Can I do it like this...  xmlNodeComplex4.ParentNode.PreviousSibling.FirstChild[REFID1].FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText   ??

Comment: check my update, I assume ID attribute is unique (let me know if it isn't), so you can just query by ID. Or do you really need the query to consider `<ZONE>` node pointed by `xmlNodeComplex4`? How?

Comment: I'll give it a shot.. thanks for your help.. If I can get it to work.. I'll check off the checkmark... thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment below. Then you can circle all nodes and when you find the one that you seek with RefID1 -> go in its children and get the type.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Element[@*]");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  if(xn.Attributes["ID"].Value == RefID1)
  {
    string type = xn.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.FirstChild.InnerText;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to use that RefID1 to go get data.. I don't need the value of the attribute.. The node with the attribute reference ID, I need data that is in one of it's children which I know how to get. I just need to get to that data via the right path as in the code I put up in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a selection node by tag and get the value of ID attribute.

```
XmlNode childNode = parentNode.SelectSingleNode("DATA");
if (childNode!= null)
{
   type = childNode.Attributes["ID"].Value;
}
```

Comment: I do not need the value of the ID of that attribute.  I already have the value of the attribute.. That value is a string called RefID1.  I want to get to data of one of the children of that node.  Look at the example I added.  I want to know if there is a way to place in the line of code something that can point to a specific location.    xmlNodeComplex4.ParentNode.PreviousSibling.FirstChild[REFID1].FirstChild.NextSib‌​ling.InnerText